# how to use regexp to match a parentheses in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I have a question about using regexp to match a parentheses in TCL.

For example I have a string like this:

```
yes, it is (true, and it is fine).
```

I just want to match this part `yes, it is (true`, how to match it?

Comment: normally enclosing parenthesis in square brackets works - "[(]"

Comment: Prefix the characters `()[]^$?.*+\ ` with the character `\ `. `\ ` is the standard regex escape character; this is not submitted as an answer because I don't actually use TCL, so it may be an exception to normal regex rules. (edit: ignore trailing spaces in code blocks, necessary or text is parsed incorrectly by SO)

Answer (score 6):

You can enclose parentheses in a character class as @bobah suggests,

```
yes, it is [(]true
```

But it's more common to escape it:

```
yes, it is \(true
```

But if you're escaping it, make sure you understand that you must either do this:

```
regexp -- "yes, it is \\(true" $subject
```

or this:

```
regexp -- {yes, it is \(true} $subject
```

Comment: Well, that's because `[]` within double quotes gets interpreted as a command in Tcl. You must either do `regexp -- {yes, it is [(]true}` or `regexp -- "yes, it is \[(\]true"`.

Comment: and also regexp -- "yes, it is \\(true" $subject does not work

Comment: @ratzip - As I already explained above, you must escape the backslash if you're going to use double quotes.

Comment: The following command returns `1` in my tclsh: `% regexp -- "yes, it is \\(true" "yes, it is (true, and it is fine)."`.

Comment: Instead of saying "It does not work," it would help if you told us what the error you're seeing is.