# Tcl [regexp]: Expression to match if block with variable inside

Tags: regex, tcl, tclsh

I want to find whether an If block is present inside a particular file.

I have a file **new.tcl** as follows:

```
if { [info exists var1] } {
  if { "$var1" == "val1" } {
    puts "var1 has value as val1"
  }
} else {
  puts "var1 does not exists"
}
```

I read this file in another Tcl function and try to match the if block through `regexp` function and the value and variable used in this function are variables.

My implementation file looks like,

```
set valueDict [list 'var1' 'val1']
set valDictLen [llength $valueDict]
set myFilePtr [open "new.tcl" "r"]
set myFileContent [read $myFilePtr]
close $myFilePtr

for { set index 0 } { $index < $valDictLen } { incr index 2 } {
  set currVar [lindex $valueDict $index]
  set currVal [lindex $valueDict [expr $index + 1]]

  # I actually want to match the entire if block content here
  if { ![regexp "if \{ \[info exists $currVal\] \}" $myFileContent] } {
    puts "Code not present"
  }
}
```

Comment: If the code is formatted nicely, you might use a regex, something like [`(?:\n|^)if\s*?{\s*?\[info exists var1\s*?]\s*?}\s*?{.*?\n}(?:\n|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/PUpBvb/1) (not tested in Tcl), but I doubt it will work in all cases. Parsing code with regex is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Please note I want to use the variable `$currVal` inside the regular expression instead of `var1` directly

Comment: take a look in this answer and tell me if it solves your problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237376/how-to-use-regexp-to-match-a-parentheses-in-tcl

Comment: No, here the main problem is that it should match `{ }[ ]` and also it needs to be enclosed within `double quotes (")` since it consists of a variable which needs to be replaced while evaluating

Comment: A couple of problems I see is a-> you are using 'val1' in your list and "val1" in your code file. b-> you need double escaping the '[' and '{' in your regexp when presenting the code in quotation marks (""), otherwise tcl will treat it as a command. when I tried your regexp without quotation marks (used curly braces and kept the '[' and '{' inside brackets), it worked

Comment: @user2141046 In that case, how will you substitute that `val1` in that code while using the `angular braces { }`  ?

Comment: This really sounds like an XY problem. Take a step back, put the regexes down, and tell us why you're trying to search some code for this statement?

Comment: @Ashwin - try separating the it into two lines - in the first, put $currVal into your expression and in the second try to regex it

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if { ![regexp "if *{ *[info exists $currVal] *}" $myFileContent] } {
    puts "Code not present"
}
```

When you use " in TCL regexp, using [ means a command/keyword to be followed.

Comment: Hi Bordoloi,This solution does not work. It actually evaluates the expression and substitute the value inside the regular expression

Comment: which tcl version u r using?

Comment: I am using Tcl 8.5.7

Comment: @Mr.Bordoloi, you need to escape the square brackets in double quotes

Comment: Can't agree. Look at below snippet. I have added in another answer. check that

Answer (score -1):

```
SBORDOLO-M-V1VG:Downloads sbordolo$ cat t3

set var1 "value"
set currVal "var1"
#set myFileContent "\[info exists var1\]"
set myFileContent {[info exists var1]}

if { ![regexp "[info exists $currVal]" $myFileContent] } {
    puts "Code not present"
} else {
    puts "Code present"
}
SBORDOLO-M-V1VG:Downloads sbordolo$ 
SBORDOLO-M-V1VG:Downloads sbordolo$ tclsh t3
Code present
SBORDOLO-M-V1VG:Downloads sbordolo$
```

Comment: Your code works by coincidence. The pattern string evaluates to 1, and so it matches any string that contains at least one 1 character.  Why not use the pattern "info exists $currVal"?

Comment: please add puts $myFileContent. It is still printing the string, not the evaluated one.Note that I have used {} not ""

Comment: I'm talking about the *pattern*, i.e. `"[info exists $currVal]"`. When the `regexp` command is invoked, it evaluates to 1, which means that the real command line is `regexp 1 [info exists var1]`.

Comment: @PeterLewerin: You are right. Thanks. Changing "[info exists $currVal]" to {[info exists $currVal]} solves the problem.

Comment: That won't work either, try "info exists $currVal" instead. (And take some time to familiarize yourself with command evaluation.)